# Problem when rendering image in React component

Tags: reactjs

I´m getting an error when trying to render an image in component.
I paste the code here.
Is it possible that I need a babel or webpack plugin?

In this component, the image rendering works fine:

```
import React from "react";

function ProductItem({ product }) {


  return product ? (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src={product.images[0]} alt={product.title} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {product.title}
        <br />
        ${product.price}
      </div>
      <p>{product.description}</p>
    </div> 
  ) : <p>Loading Product... </p>;
}; 

export default ProductItem;
```

In this other component is where I have the problem.
ProductDetail.js

```
import React from "react";
import useGetProducts from "../hooks/useGetProducts";

const API = 'https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products';

function ProductDetail() {

  const data = useGetProducts(`${API}/6`);

  return (
    <>
      {data.products
        ? 
        <>
            <h3>{data.products.title}</h3>
            <p>{data.products.description}</p>
            <div>
              <img src={data.products.images[0]} alt="title" />
            </div>
        </>
        : <h4>Loading...</h4>
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

[image]

Custom Hook with useEffect, the useGetProducts function  is responsible for bringing the data from the API with the Axios library

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useGetProducts = (API) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios(API);
        setProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return { products, error, loaded };
};

export default useGetProducts
```

Answer (score 3):

Your default state for products is `[]`, so the conditional render `data.products` in ProductDetail.js always return true so you can change default state for products is `null`

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
```

Comment: It works fine in ProductDetails.js.  

  but in home (ProductList.js) 
{data.products.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id}>
            <ProductItem product={product} />
            <div>
              <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>{product.title}</Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
  
now I get this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Comment: @alejandro try this {data.products &&  data.products.map(....} or {data.products?.map(....}

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is correct, so I will not duplicate it, but I see room for improvement in your code/example.

Your useGetProducts hook is very easy to break and hard to reuse. If you will pass the wrong URL or the structure of the API will change it will break your code. Also, the hook is not very generic, cause you will need to create similar fn for each entity. My suggestion. Use [react-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query) and separate functions for calling API. So it will look like this.

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function ProductPage() {
  const productResponse = useQuery('exchanges', () => getProduct('6'))
  const { isLoading, isError, data: product } = productResponse

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {isError && <div>Something went wrong :(</div>}

      {product && (
        <div>
          <h1>Product title: {product.title}</h1>

          <p>
            {product.images.map(imageSrc => (
              <img key={imageSrc} src={imageSrc} alt="" />
            ))}
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

interface Product {
  id: string
  title: string
  images: string[]
}

function getProduct(id: string): Promise<Product> {
  return axios
    .get(`https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products/${id}`)
    .then(r => r.data)
}
```

PS. react-query requires additional configuration ( context provider, config, etc ). Please look into docs on how to use it.